# Mozilla Crash Reporter displayed every day

Tags: firefox

Every day I get back from work and I see this message (Image attached) - I didn't run the Firefox browser. Any idea how to solve this?

UPDATE:
I pressed on the "Details..." Button and here is the full log:

[image]

```
AdapterDeviceID: 0x1912
AdapterDriverVersion: 27.20.100.8682
AdapterSubsysID: 00000000
AdapterVendorID: 0x8086
AvailablePageFile: 33774526464
AvailablePhysicalMemory: 28338905088
AvailableVirtualMemory: 138531429449728
BuildID: 20210912185727
CPUMicrocodeVersion: 0xcc
ContentSandboxCapable: 1
ContentSandboxLevel: 6
CrashTime: 1631667042
InstallTime: 1631616570
LauncherProcessState: 0
ModuleSignatureInfo: {"Microsoft Corporation":["VCRUNTIME140.dll","msvcp140.dll","VCRUNTIME140_1.dll"],"Microsoft Windows":["msi.dll","ondemandconnroutehelper.dll","AudioSes.dll","wininet.dll","npmproxy.dll","winrnr.dll","wshbth.dll","pnrpnsp.dll","NapiNSP.dll","dbgcore.dll","winmm.dll","dbghelp.dll","Windows.Globalization.dll","DWrite.dll","urlmon.dll","iertutil.dll","icm32.dll","BCP47mrm.dll","rasadhlp.dll","ColorAdapterClient.dll","InputHost.dll","TextInputFramework.dll","mscms.dll","Windows.UI.dll","Bcp47Langs.dll","dhcpcsvc.dll","dhcpcsvc6.DLL","winnsi.dll","WindowManagementAPI.dll","twinapi.appcore.dll","usp10.dll","MMDevAPI.dll","version.dll","FWPUCLNT.DLL","winhttp.dll","srvcli.dll","avrt.dll","netprofm.dll","wscapi.dll","propsys.dll","nlaapi.dll","wsock32.dll","wtsapi32.dll","WinTypes.dll","dcomp.dll","CoreUIComponents.dll","CoreMessaging.dll","uxtheme.dll","dwmapi.dll","kernel.appcore.dll","windows.storage.dll","dxgi.dll","ntmarta.dll","rsaenh.dll","IPHLPAPI.DLL","dnsapi.dll","netutils.dll","mswsock.dll","CRYPTBASE.DLL","wldp.dll","cryptsp.dll","msasn1.dll","devobj.dll","umpdc.dll","powrprof.dll","sspicli.dll","userenv.dll","profapi.dll","crypt32.dll","wintrust.dll","cfgmgr32.dll","KERNELBASE.dll","bcrypt.dll","win32u.dll","bcryptPrimitives.dll","msvcp_win.dll","gdi32full.dll","ucrtbase.dll","setupapi.dll","shlwapi.dll","sechost.dll","msvcrt.dll","nsi.dll","rpcrt4.dll","msctf.dll","gdi32.dll","shell32.dll","oleaut32.dll","combase.dll","imagehlp.dll","kernel32.dll","psapi.dll","ole32.dll","ws2_32.dll","SHCore.dll","advapi32.dll","clbcatq.dll","user32.dll","imm32.dll","ntdll.dll"],"Mozilla Corporation":["firefox.exe","xul.dll","nss3.dll","freebl3.dll","mozglue.dll","nssckbi.dll","softokn3.dll","lgpllibs.dll"]}
MozCrashReason: MOZ_CRASH(Shutdown hanging after all known phases and workers finished.)
Notes: FP(D00-L1000-W00001000-T000) 
DWrite? DWrite+ WR? WR+ 
ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox
ReleaseChannel: aurora
SafeMode: 0
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 151203
ShutdownProgress: xpcom-shutdown
StartupCrash: 0
StartupTime: 1631666970
SystemMemoryUsePercentage: 17
ThreadIdNameMapping: 3676:"IPC I/O Parent",3868:"JS Watchdog",11896:"TaskController Thread #0",12988:"TaskController Thread #1",10320:"TaskController Thread #3",9872:"TaskController Thread #2",12088:"TaskController Thread #4",12244:"TaskController Thread #5",3020:"TaskController Thread #6",5032:"TaskController Thread #7",7196:"WindowsVsyncThread",7356:"WRWorker#0",6908:"WRWorker#1",10640:"WRWorker#2",4824:"WRWorker#3",5020:"WRWorker#4",4900:"WRWorker#5",6248:"WRWorker#6",12076:"WRWorker#7",9320:"WRWorkerLP#0",1192:"WRWorkerLP#1",9836:"WRWorkerLP#2",12848:"WRWorkerLP#3",6132:"WRWorkerLP#4",5980:"WRWorkerLP#5",3176:"WRWorkerLP#6",4668:"WRWorkerLP#7",13068:"BitsCommander",3552:"Shutdown Hang Terminator",1300:"Shutdown Statistics Writer",
Throttleable: 1
TotalPageFile: 39441178624
TotalPhysicalMemory: 34224513024
TotalVirtualMemory: 140737488224256
URL: 
UptimeTS: 728.57352
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 93.0
Winsock_LSP: MSAFD Tcpip [TCP/IP] : 2 : 2 : 1 : 6 : 0x20066 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : e70f1aa0-ab8b-11cf-8ca3-00805f48a192 
 MSAFD Tcpip [UDP/IP] : 2 : 2 : 2 : 17 : 0x20609 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : e70f1aa0-ab8b-11cf-8ca3-00805f48a192 
 MSAFD Tcpip [RAW/IP] : 2 : 2 : 3 : 0 : 0x20609 : 0xc : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : e70f1aa0-ab8b-11cf-8ca3-00805f48a192 
 MSAFD Tcpip [TCP/IPv6] : 2 : 23 : 1 : 6 : 0x20066 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : f9eab0c0-26d4-11d0-bbbf-00aa006c34e4 
 MSAFD Tcpip [UDP/IPv6] : 2 : 23 : 2 : 17 : 0x20609 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : f9eab0c0-26d4-11d0-bbbf-00aa006c34e4 
 MSAFD Tcpip [RAW/IPv6] : 2 : 23 : 3 : 0 : 0x20609 : 0xc : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : f9eab0c0-26d4-11d0-bbbf-00aa006c34e4 
 AF_UNIX : 2 : 1 : 1 : 0 : 0x20026 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : a00943d9-9c2e-4633-9b59-0057a3160994 
 RSVP TCPv6 Service Provider : 2 : 23 : 1 : 6 : 0x22066 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 9d60a9e0-337a-11d0-bd88-0000c082e69a 
 RSVP TCP Service Provider : 2 : 2 : 1 : 6 : 0x22066 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 9d60a9e0-337a-11d0-bd88-0000c082e69a 
 RSVP UDPv6 Service Provider : 2 : 23 : 2 : 17 : 0x22609 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 9d60a9e0-337a-11d0-bd88-0000c082e69a 
 RSVP UDP Service Provider : 2 : 2 : 2 : 17 : 0x22609 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 9d60a9e0-337a-11d0-bd88-0000c082e69a 
 Hyper-V RAW : 2 : 34 : 1 : 1 : 0x20026 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 1234191b-4bf7-4ca7-86e0-dfd7c32b5445 
 MSAFD L2CAP [Bluetooth] : 2 : 32 : 1 : 256 : 0x20006 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 9fc48064-7298-43e4-b7bd-181f2089792a 
 MSAFD RfComm [Bluetooth] : 2 : 32 : 1 : 3 : 0x20026 : 0x8 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll :  : 9fc48064-7298-43e4-b7bd-181f2089792a
useragent_locale: en-US

This report also contains technical information about the state of the application when it crashed.
```

[image]

Comment: What do you see if you click "Details"? Do you see anything in the Event Viewer?

Comment: I didn't check the 'details', I will do so next time and will update the question.
In the Event Viewer I don't see anything related to Firefox, what am I supposed to look for?

Comment: There might be nothing in the Event Viewer. When you have more info add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.

Comment: If "Details" isn't enough, after submitting the crash report you can enter **about:crashes** in the Firefox URL bar, which might give you additional information

Comment: @harrymc I updated my question.

Comment: Have you updated firefox lately? Are your graphics card drivers up to date? Have you tried disabling all extensions to see if they are causing the crash?  You also appear to be using a beta version of the browser (93.0) while the current version is 92.0.1 (https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/notes/). have you tried downgrading to a "stable" release or contacting Mozilla?

Comment: When do the crashes happen? Is it immediately after waking up the PC? Is it after some number of hours? Is there a specific website you go to where it happens? You should [edit] your question to provide more details.

Comment: @Mokubai I update FireFox every week